# ACTION_SEND в android

Tags: java, android

Написал такое activity:

```
public class SendWelcomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("*/*".equals(type)) {
                try {
                    Person person = (Person) intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                    SerializationAndDeserialization.writeToFile(person.getName(), person, this);
                    saveName(person.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unknown format of file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        finish();
    }

    private void saveName(String name) {
        InformationAboutPersons inf = new InformationAboutPersons();
        String[] names = inf.getNames(this);
        if (names != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (names[i].equals(name)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            inf.addNamePerson(name, this);
        } else {
            inf.addNamePerson(name, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот она в манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".Controller.SendWelcomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Она должна открывать файл, в котором находится объект, и сохранять его.

Вот как я отправляю этот файл по email:

```
try {
    String FILENAME = "filesLifeOrganizationRe" + mPerson.getName() + ".person";

    File imageFile = getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

    this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), 1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Отправка файла вроде работает, но почему то когда я нажимаю на файл в gmail, то он говорит, что этот файл не поддерживается установленными приложениями. Да и само открытие файла не работает, person = null. Не знаю, как все сделать правильно 
PS: я новичок в программировании

Comment: У вас расширение файла `person`. Смените его на `txt` например

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Поменял, все то же